# How to connect to a local postgreSQL database from a remote pc

Tags: postgresql, remote-access

I am pretty new to everything that is database management, remote connection etc... And I need this for a university project.
I have a local postgreSQL database on my Windows computer, which I access through localhost. What I want to do now is connect to this database using my laptop (which is in the same WLAN, don't know if that helps).

I changed the file `pg_hba.conf`, and added `host all all 0.0.0.0/0 md5` and `host all all ::0/0 md5`. Also in the `postgresql.conf` file, there is one line `listen_addresses = '*'` which was the default, but as I understand it it is what it needs to be so a non-localhost can connect to the database.

How can I do this? On my laptop I tried running psql and for the server I put the IPv4 address of my PC(where the local database is stored), but it doesn't connect (`Connection timed out`)

Comment: Disable the firewall on your PC

Comment: A more secure solution would be to open port 5432 in your firewall. This assumes you Postgres server is running under the default port of 5432. To verify check ```port``` setiing in postgresql.conf.

Comment: It works! I set up a custom incoming firewall regulation for postgre, so that i don't have to disable the whole firewall. Thanks!